# Bootstrap Dropdowns button not working with Angular 8 component

Tags: css, angular, typescript, bootstrap-4, drop-down-menu

I am trying to show dropdown menu using bootstrap4.3 class but after selecting on menu nothing will happen I ma using angular 8 version.

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"> Dropdown button </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please can you share the code you have tried so far.

Comment: You can [edit] your question, please don't post code in comments

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dropdown functionality in Bootstrap requires **bootstrap.js** & **jquery.js**; But we shouldn't use these in Angular; So we use a library dedicated for using Bootstrap with Angular & look up [dropdown functionality there](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/dropdown/examples)

relevant **HTML**:

```
    <div ngbDropdown class="d-inline-block">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="dropdownMenuButton" ngbDropdownToggle>Dropdown button</button>
        <div ngbDropdownMenu aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
          <button ngbDropdownItem>Action</button>
          <button ngbDropdownItem>Another Action</button>
          <button ngbDropdownItem>Something else here</button>
        </div>
      </div>
```

complete [working stackblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rw5km5)

Answer (score 5):

Bootstrap dependencies are `popper.js` and `jquery`. Once you install bootstrap in your angular app, it will show you the dependencies, then install them and add them in your angular.json in scripts (see the below picture). The versions compatible are Bootstrap@4.3.1 (the dropdown issue fixed in this version) and popper.js@1.14.7

## dependency for dropdown is popper.js in bootstrap

[image]

So with the above order, now the dropdown will work. Even with latest versions(4.5.x) of bootstrap works. You do not have to use another third party library/package manager for that, if you do not prefer. Thanks. Please see the relevant markup below, taken from bootstrap.

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown button
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: We have to follow the exact order given above. Unless it'll not work. Thanks.